# How to make multiple callout as asynchronous from single component?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, trigger, lightning

[image]

I have one single component which will make two different callouts and append data to two sections.

I want these two-component to load asynchronously so that whichever data comes the first will load first.

But it is now working as expected when I checked network tab in chrome console callouts is concatenated to each other.

```
doInit : {
  helper.callout1();//event based callout
  helper.callout2();//event based callout
}
```

Comment: I added the information we already have to this question, including some hints on how you can deal with this, why it happens, etc. Please let us know if this answers your inquiry sufficiently.

Comment: @sfdcfox yes, now I could understand what does it mean by box carrying after seeing the references 

but while searching as a lame person like me without keyword boxcarried couldn't found anything over the internet.

So I would suggest to keep this post open and refer the original post as the answer.